# How can I load all tag files in a directory?

Tags: vim, ctags

In my `.vimrc` I load many tag files like this:

```
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/boost_filesystem_1_55_0
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/boost_program_options_1_55_0
...
...
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/zlib_1_2_8
```

If I add a new tag file or update an existing one, I have to remember to change the `.vimrc` file. Can I just do something like this:?

```
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/* "Load all tag files in this directory.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try another approach. Rename all files to `mytags` and use different paths to get them. like:

```
~/.vim/tags/boost_filesystem_1_55_0/mytags
~/.vim/tags/boost_program_options_1_55_0/mytags
~/.vim/tags/zlib_1_2_8/mytags
...
```

And as value of `tags` use `~/.vim/tags/**/mytags`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. If ** can match all directories, surely there's something to match all files?